# mysql база данных (.frm) (.MYD) (.MYI)

Tags: mysql

Друзья подскажите как это дело открыть, спасибо!:)
http://vk.cc/1eRKvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поставить себе MySQL сервер. Не старее, чем стоял там, где брали. Если не знаете попробуйте что-то типа 5.5.
2. Создать базу данных сердствами сервера.
3. Остановить процесс сервера и залить эти файлы во вновь созданную базу данных. Залить - значить скопировать, а не переименовать.
4. Запустить сервер. Подключиться к БД.
5. Пользовать.

Comment: По большому счету П.2 можно опустить, и просто создать в папке \data\ сервера папку в которую и залить ваши файлики.

Comment: щас буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

зачем? phpmyadmin.net, [mysql workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)